# Inequality Regarding e

Tags: inequality

A proof done in class called upon this inequality:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\lt e\lt\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
How can this inequality be proven?

Comment: How was $e$ defined - as the limit of $(1+\frac 1n)^n$?

Comment: I bet this question has been asked here dozen of times. A classical approach is to show, through the Bernoulli's inequality, that the sequences appearing in the LHS and RHS are both monotonic (increasing LHS, decreasing RHS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sequences have $e$ as the limit, so it suffices to show that the left sequence is increasing and the right sequence is decreasing.

Use the AM-GM inequality to get
$$\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\frac{\frac{n+1}n+\ldots+\frac{n+1}n+1}{n+1}>\sqrt[n+1\,]{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n}$$
It follows that
$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

For the other sequence use the HM-GM inequality to get
$$\frac{n+2}{n+1}=\frac{n+2}{\frac n{n+1}+\ldots+\frac n{n+1}+1}<\sqrt[n+2\,]{\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^{n+1}}$$
It follows that
$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}>\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+2}$$

Comment: @Meelo Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is strictly increasing and converging to $e$. This implies the first inequality.

$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ is strictly decreasing and converging to $e$. This implies the first inequality.