# Prove that $\frac{1}{n+1}<\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1tdt<\frac1n$

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, logarithms, taylor-expansion

> Prove the following inequality $$\frac{1}{n+1}<\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1tdt<\frac1n$$

Following is my approach:
$$\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1tdt=\ln(n+1)-\ln n$$
$$\implies \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac1tdt=\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})=\ln(1+\frac1n)$$
From Taylor's theorem we have $\ln(1+x)<x,\enspace \forall \enspace x\in \enspace (0,1)$
$$\implies \ln(1+\frac1n)<\frac1n$$
This is where I am stuck. I am unable to prove the other inequality. I tried a lot but I couldn't.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: About the other inequality, see [Inequality Regarding e](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012215/inequality-regarding-e)

Comment: @dxiv it did answer my question . Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n <t<n+1$ we have $\frac  1 {n+1}<\frac  1t <\frac 1 n$. Integrate  from $n$ to $n+1$ and see what you get.